# orWhere and whereHas combination not working in laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

```
$orders = Order::where([
                ['user_account_id', Auth::user()->user_account_id],
                ['order_status_id', '1']
            ])->orWhere([
                ['user_account_id', Auth::user()->user_account_id],
                ['order_status_id', '5']
            ])->whereHas('event', function($query) {
                $query->where('end_date', '>', Carbon::now());
            })->paginate(10);
```

In my query `whereHas` part is not working if `orWhere` is used, otherwise fine

What's wrong with it? Help, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$orders =   Order::where(function($query){
                $query->where(
                    ['user_account_id', Auth::user()->user_account_id],
                    ['order_status_id', '1']
                ])->orWhere([
                    ['user_account_id', Auth::user()->user_account_id],
                    ['order_status_id', '5']
                ])})
            ->whereHas('event', function($query) {
                $query->where('end_date', '>', Carbon::now());
            })->paginate(10);
```

OR

```
$orders =   Order::where('user_account_id', Auth::user()->user_account_id)
            ->whereIN('order_status_id',[1,5])
            ->whereHas('event', function($query) {
                $query->where('end_date', '>', Carbon::now());
            })->paginate(10);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution could be using the `whereIn` method which checks whether the value is in a given array. This prevents you from needing to use the orWhere at all.

```
    $orders = Order::where('user_account_id', Auth::user()->user_account_id)
        ->whereIn('order_status_id', ['1', '5'])
        ->whereHas('event', function($query) {
            $query->where('end_date', '>', Carbon::now());
        })->paginate(10);
```